# Global name not working in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables, curses

I am coding a program where I am using curses to create a UI and I have gotten the width and height of the terminal via a different command and I want to make those two variables global so that I can refer to them throughout the program without having to pass them in through parameters everytime (unless I should just do that?) here is a simple layout of the series of calls I have:

```
def three():
    print width, height

def two():
    three()

def one():
    two()

global width
global height

width, height = console.getTerminalSize()

one()
```

So I am getting the global name not defined error but not sure why as I have defined them as global first then called the series of functions, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define `global` out in the main code; any variables declared there are global by default. You need to place `global width` and `global height` in the function where you call them. That tells Python to use the global version of the variable instead of making a local one with that name (which is the default behavior).

But to answer your other question: using globals is generally undesirable, and it's better to pass in parameters when you can. It's less risky.

[Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them?rq=1)